# Embedding PHP in body tag class

Tags: php, html, css

When trying to do the following:

```
<body class="<?php echo $mBodyBg; ?>">
```

to utilize a script which checks the page and changes the Background accordingly it doesn't work.

I know the script works because when I use `<title><?php echo $mTitle;?></title>` the title changes page to page.

The file structure I use is:

```
/ - root (working on index.php)
/css - 
/scripts - where the script is comming from
/img
```

The CSS code is:

```
.bodyHome{
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
}
```

The snippet of PHP code from the script where everything else functions is:

```
case "home" : {
        $mBodyBg = "bodyHome";
        $mTitle = "Testing";
        $mPageTitle = "INTRODUCING Blah";
        $mCssTest = "well well-lg";
    }
    break;
```

the variable points to a CSS class name which in turn points to the background image (the file path has been checked and played with at least 20 times), I have had no problem embedding other CSS class names in exactly the same way. Why is the body tag different?

When i look in dev tools at the body tag nothng is embedded... it outputs `<body class="">`

Comment: What is the output when you view the source of the page?  What are the related styles in the stylesheet?

Comment: The body tag is no different than other tags.  It's far more likely there is an issue with your CSS or that $bodyBg doesn't point to what you think it does.  View source on the resultant page to ensure that it's emitting the proper class, and then check your CSS to make sure that it's grabbing the right definition.

Comment: It's not different. It's all text at the end of the day. Share some more of your code - your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What do you see in firebug/developer tools?

Comment: To narrow the problem down, I suggest trying a known class name in place of `<?php echo $bodyBg; ?>`.  If it works, you know there's a problem with your php variable.  If it doesn't, you know it's likely the CSS.

Comment: You have extra quotes, `"'bodyHome'"` should be `"bodyHome"`

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I apologise they were left in from endless reworkings, they were never tehre in the first place. I've removed them back to original... no luck

Comment: It's 100% for sure a mistake on your end, not an issue or bug with PHP or HTML itself. What is the output of `exit(var_dump($mBodyBg))`? Please also turn on error reporting.

Comment: Your background image should also read `background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);`  The path is relative to your css file.

Comment: Cheers SuperJer - more endless tweaks ... it did and it does again... thanks... Sunjay's nailed it, defining the variable first causes everything to work with it... Im still at a bit of a loss as to why i only have to define this one variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body tag is no different than any other tag as far as PHP is concerned. Take a look at your code and make sure the $mBodyBg variable is defined BEFORE the place you are using it in. If it isn't defined, your code will not work.

Comment: BOOM! why is this the case here and not with anything else? I mean $mtitle isnt defined and that works

Comment: I'm guessing your code is structured so your PHP is somewhere in your body tag. Except in a few cases with some special syntax, all PHP does with a web page is essentially find and replace PHP tags with their evaluated forms. If a variable that you're trying to "echo" onto a page doesn't exist while it's being echoed, you can't use it and it won't work as you'd expect.

Comment: I defined $mBodyBG at the top of the script which it wasnt before and now everything works.
And please dont down vote me Wesley, not cool.